# Search output in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a textbox in aspx page and a button.
I also have a gridview that should list result based on a stored procedure.

Here is my C# code example

```
private void GetList(string EmployeeName)    
String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "GetEmployeeDetailsByName";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeName", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtName.Text.Trim();        
    cmd.Connection = con;
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        GridView1.EmptyDataText = "No Records Found";
        GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }
```

Now I added the following in button_click event

```
GetList();
```

it gives me "no overload for method..." error.

how do I make sure that whatever user types in the search textbox passes into `GetList(**HERE**)` in .cs file?

Comment: A method that is named `GetList` should return something. You could return the DataSource of the Grid(f.e. a DataTable). Otherwise i would name it `DataBindGrid`.

Answer (score 3):

You have no overload of `GetList` that takes no argument, so this doesn't compile:

```
GetList();
```

I would change the type of the parameter to `int` since that is the required type:

```
private void GetList(int EmployeeID)
```

Then pass the parsed `TextBox.Text` (after you have valiated that it can be parsed):

```
int EmployeeID = int.Parse(txtID.Text.Trim());
GetList(EmployeeID);
```

and change this line:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtID.Text.Trim();
```

to

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = EmployeeID;
```

Comment: I get "The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not String objects." error I am using string as the search text format (not int as posted originally)

Comment: @user1569220: So `EmployeeID` is really a `varchar`, why?

Comment: That code is an example I am following. The search I will be doing is on nvarchar fields in the database. so i.e search text could be Erick and I want to run a stored proc which accepts one parameter > show some fields associated with Eric in a gridview upon clicking.

Comment: @user1569220: I think that the exception is in your stored-procedure, so you should start looking there. Does it work if you pass "Erick" instead of  his ID?

Comment: I am just using ID as an example (now I know it was a bad example). I have updated the original post.

Comment: @user1569220: So what happens if you call the method in this way: `GetList(txtID.Text.Trim())`? I don't know if you have unerstood my answer since the important part is not that i'm using `int` but that i'm calling the method with an argument.

Comment: I get ""The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not String objects." error I am using string as the search text format (not int as posted originally)" with "cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeName", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtName.Text.Trim();   " line being highlighted in light green

Comment: @user1569220: Try to split this statemtent on three lines, so initializing the parameter, setting the value and adding the parameter to the SqlParameterCollection. You could also use `AddWithValue`.

Answer (score 2):

Button.Click event is a System.EventHandler event delegate type.

Your method GetList() must accept 2 parameters:

GetList(object sender, EventArgs e)

Hope this help!

Comment: I think that you have misunderstood: _"Now I added the following in button_click event: 
GetList();"_ I assume that the event-handler is not `GetList` but he called that method there.

Comment: Ops..my bad.. But.. The EmployeeID parameter in GetList() isn't used!

Comment: I refresh the page just now, your post mean already this thing @TimSchmelter

Answer (score 0):

I used a different method (by creating datatable and binding that to adaptor..) to get this to work. Thank you for trying to help me solve the issue.